After replacing bathroom outlets they dont work
I replaced my Mom's bathroom outlets. I put the wires from the older ones directly to the same spots on the new outlets.. same style and same types. Most regular flat faced outlets and one GFI after the first outlet. Picture shows you the first set with the GFI in it. But after replacing them all it seems as if none of them work and the GFI is not reseting or working at all. Any ideas of what's going on? Like I said I hooked them all up as the old ones I took out. 

Unfotunately we don't have Xray vision. You need to provide photographs of the inside wiring of both sockets. Are you sure they worked before you did anything? Have you checked to see if a circuit breaker has tripped?

from this photo the only thing we can say, you screwed the wiring somewhere

turn the breaker back on

These are the old outlets. First in the string on the right. I just set them up the way these were. And yes the breakers were back on and yes they were working before. These are at my mom's place an hr drive away I can snap pictures of the wires when I get there... she wants me to fix I just don't know what could be wrong.. I screwed the wires same places they were on the old outlets.

When doing work an hour away, always check it before leaving. Now you know...

Assuming you turned on the feed circuit after replacing the sockets...
The GFCI has to be the first socket in the bathroom in order to protect all the others.
My money is on Line and Load on the GFCI being reversed.
Check that the Line connections on the GFCI are connected to the live input circuit. The Load connections are the ones which feed all other sockets in the bathroom.
To identify the live input circuit - disconnect all four connections to the GFCI, and make sure none touch each other. Turn on the circuit, and see which black/white pair show voltage on your tester (you DO have a non-contact voltage tester, I hope..). The pair which have voltage are the ones you connect to the Line inputs.

Just to reinforce, top and bottom wire locations are meaningless on gfci receptacles.  They vary by mfr.

Oh. I see. I can do that thanks for the information.

I figured out what was wrong, the new gfi's the line and load spots are switched so I have the wires that should have been on the top on the bottom and bottom on top...so swapped those and now everything works great.  Thanks everyone for the help.
